# FluentWait function cannot be used in function of Java Class

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

This maybe a basic question but I am not quite familiar with Java and Selenium Webdriver. I don't know why Eclipse shows Error to change 'Function' as 'Remove type arguments' by Eclipse. I want to use fluentwait as function in my class. Or what is the right way to use it?

```
public class Process()
   {
    public void Start()
    {
        //function call
        WebElement index = fluentWait(By.xpath("xxx"), driver);
    }   

    //function method
    public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator, WebDriver driver) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(locator);
            }
        });

        return  foo;
    };
   }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem locally, maybe you could add which `Wait` and `Function` classes you're importing? Btw., I had to remove the brackets after `Process` - it is a class, not a function.

Comment: @blalasaadri Your suggestion might be what I am missing in my Java Project. I imported as: import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait; but how can I import for the 'Function' ?

Comment: You probably want `import com.google.common.base.Function;` in your imports then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've failed to import `com.google.common.base.Function`.